# Setting Ingestion Settings Using the YouTube Live Streaming API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am creating a live event using the YouTube Live Streaming API in JavaScript. When I create my [liveStream](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) resource I set the following settings:

```js
"cdn":
  {
   "format":"1080p",
   "ingestionType":"rtmp"
  }
```

However, whenever I then view my event on my YouTube account, the ingestion settings do not have the bitrate selected- [3000 Kbps-6000 Kbps (1080p)]. Instead I see the following:

[ ] Basic Ingestion 
[X] Custom Ingestion 
[Select a Stream v]

Custom ingestion settings is selected, but no stream is set. What could be preventing the liveStream from having its bitrate set (1080p selected beneath custom ingestion)?

P.S. I apologize for any errors, or if I need to be more clear. This is my first question that I have posted on SO. Let me know if I can clear anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It wasn't in my creation of my `liveBroadcast` or my `liveStream` resources, it was that I wasn't making the call to `liveBroadcasts.bind()` correctly. I was creating two different objects that I was passing as arguments- one containing the id and part of the `liveBroadcast`, and one containing the id of the `liveStream` with which I wanted to bind the broadcast.
I was doing this:

`liveBroadcasts.bind({id: broadcastId, part: 'snippet,status'}, {streamId: streamId});`

This was giving my request a body that contained the streamId. However, the bind method does NOT have a request body. I needed to include the streamId with the rest of the parameters like so:

```
liveBroadcasts.bind({id: broadcastId, part: 'snippet,status',streamId: streamId});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/create_broadcast.py could make it clear for you.

Programmatically, you can not set one of the default streams.

So you create a new stream, set it's ingestion properties then bind that stream into your event.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ibrahim. Good to know that you can't set the default streams programmatically. It was my bind that wasn't working properly.